# Deserializing of Google's Translate API result in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, google-translate, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize Google's Translate API JSON response into an C# object using JavaScriptSerializer. However, it always says `Type 'TranslateAPI.Models.Translations' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`. I double checked whether I have correctly created models for this object and it seems right. Here are my models:

```
TranslateResult
    public TranslateData data { get; set; }

TranslateData
    public Translations translations { get; set; }

Translations
    public TranslatedText[] translatedText { get; set; } // I have also tried List<TranslatedText> which also doesn't work

TranslatedText
    public string translatedText { get; set; }
```

The json returned from Google looks like this:

```
{data: {
    translations: [
        {translatedText: "Hello world"}
    ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

PS. It could be useful to mention, that I'm deserializing it like so: `TranslateResult translateResult = js.Deserialize <TranslateResult>(json);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't need the `Translations` class at all. You've got:

- An object containing a `data` property
- The `data` property value is an object containing a `translations` property
- The `translations` property value is an array
- Each element of the array is an object with a `translatedText` property

So that sounds to me like your `TranslateData` class should be:

```
TranslateData
    public Translation[] translations { get; set; }

Translation // Renamed from TranslatedText
    public string translatedText { get; set }
```

(I'd also recommend that you rename the properties to follow normal C# naming conventions, and then apply attributes to help with the JSON conversion if you need to. I haven't used `JavaScriptSerializer` for a while, but I'm sure it's feasible. You shouldn't need to work with nasty property names in your C# code.)

Comment: I don't understand how could I miss that ... you were right with the array, thanks! I'll also look at the attributes and following correct naming conventions.

Comment: For those who are having similar problem - I was not supposed to have array for Translation (Translation[]) but an array for TranslatedText[].

Comment: This is kind of an old thread, but you can also make the "translations" property a generic list (List<Translation>) and get all of the generic goodness!  :)

Comment: @coach_rob: These days I'd recommend using Google.Cloud.Translate.V2 anyway, as it's an easier library to use. I posted this answer long before I started the library :)